# how to open and print all the files in a directory

Tags: c, unix

I am working on a code to figure out the cpu usage of all the processes that are currently running. Exactly what the Top command does. I am having some difficultly in trying to get all the process pids in the system. I know that pids are in /proc directory. Could anyone please help me how to open all the files at a time. Or is there any way that I could store all the pid numbers in an array. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look up opendir call.

Comment: thank you very much. I have read the man opendir. Still i find somewhat difficult. Can I get the names of all the subdirectory in the directory. Could you please provide an example program.

Comment: Search "opendir" on SO or on google.

Comment: @vijay kumar kdp: It's the other way around: you need to provide SO with a program and explain how it is broken. SO will then help you with a fix.

Answer (score 1):

This could be one of your implementation(rough steps). You would have to do error
handling and size management while implementing.For more information you should refer to some manual/book as suggested by others. Also you should aware about security feature as some of directory may not have read permission. Please try to understand these concepts before implementing.

```
#define MAX_ENTRY 3000
struct dirent *entry[MAX_ENTRY] = {NULL};
struct stat    sb[MAX_ENTRY];
// name = "/proc"
dir = opendir( name);
for(i =0; ; i++) {
 entry[i] = readdir(dir);
 if (entry[i] == NULL)
    break;
}   

for(j = 0;j < i ;j++) {
 ret = stat( entry[j]->d_name, &sb[j]);
 //now check the attribute of sb[j].st_mode to determine whether directory 
 //or not. in this case /proc directory maintains one directory per process.
 //Additionally you may want to check that name contains all numbers not any
 //characters to double sure that you are fetching PID of a process not other
 // directory maintained by /proc

  if(S_ISDIR(sb[j].st_mode)) {
   // This should print like 0,1,2,3,4...........You can store it in some 
   // different dynamic array. Now you can use this list of PID for your 
   // actual work.
    printf("%s\n",entry[j]->d_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyways you can open a pipe and do whatever you want, pipes are costly though but you can use them as an alternative when nothing is available. You can tweak command and do whatever you wish to.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void printList(char* pdirname)
{
   if(NULL == pdirname)
   return;

   char command[256];
   sprintf(command,"find %s -maxdepth 1 -type d ",pdirname);

   FILE * fp = popen(command, "r");
   char arr[255];
   while( NULL != fgets(arr,255, fp))
   {
     printf("%s", arr);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
if(argc != 2)
{
  printf("wrong input: usage -./a.out <dirname> e.g. :: ./a.out /usr/local \n");
  return 0;
}

printList(argv[1]);

return (0);
}
```